# Log distance path loss model where distance is the unknown

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I need help understanding the last leap that a lecturer took today in class

Log-distance PL Model

PL(d) = PLo(do) + 10nLog10 d/do

We found the sum another way so PL(d) = 140dbm, and we were asked to find d(distance)

PLo(do) = -20log10(0.316)/(4x3.142x100)

PLo(do) = 71.99

where n=3.5 my tutor managed to get the distance(d), he wrote down the steps but I don't understand the math

10nLog10 d/do = (10*3.5)*log10(d/do)

the above is as far as I can get with my understanding, ELI5 would be a great help as my math gets limited quick

Comment: It seems as though you know that $140 = 71.99 + 10\times 3.5 \times \log_{10} ({d}/d_0)$, and you want to solve for $d$. Is this correct? And do you know the value of $d_0$ to use?

Comment: The value of do is 10 meters and yes I want to find d, I asked for explain like I'm five because I can't figure the math, or rather the thinking to how you get there if that makes sense, I can grasp math when the way to work is explained but I've never had higher learning at it, again not sure but the algebraic steps to finding a value based on result doesn't make sense to me